# Serialization Exception with mvc SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

we have at least 10-15 view models which are using SelectListItem and now we have got a requirement to store the view model data in session. In attempt to store the value in the session below is the exception I am getting. We have references to SelectListItem in so many places that any changes to model will be time-consuming. Any recommendations on resolving the issue ?

```
 An exception of type 
'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'    
 occurred in Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider.dll but was not    
 handled in user code

Additional information: Type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' in 
Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.
```

Below is one of the several view models we are storing in session

```
[Serializable]
public class PrivacyViewModel
{

   public int SelectedProductId { get; set; }

   public String AcquisitionChannel { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductList { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AcquisitionChannelList { get; 
    set; }

   public Boolean HasReadDisclaimer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try to use cache instead of session ?

Comment: I don't understand exactly your requirement, but you might know that to store data with Redis we need to serialize it, and exception says that SelectListItem is not serializable. You can create your own class marked with serializable to store same data.